# Error when trying to run rails server (Gemfile not found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've ran into a error that haven't happened before and haven't found a real solution online. Everytime I try to run a rails command like rails server or rails generate scaffold I get the following error:

> D:/myrailsapp/config/.../Gemfile not found

Any ideas how to fix this? I had it working after the error without doing anything and now I can't run it again.

Comment: Can you please navigate to your project's root directory and type: `~/project_root> ls` and paste the output?

Comment: @xdmanmagiconsei In what directory are you running the command? It looks like you are running it from some subdirectory. The `rails server` command looks for the Gemfile in the current directory. But the path you pasted seems to be from a subdirectory of your project.

Comment: Check your root project directory for presence of 'Gemfile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be related to this https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/issues/138

try running

`gem update`